# Another question on Spring 3, servlet, @autowired

Tags: spring, servlets, datasource, autowired

I think I've read every question and answer on Spring and autowiring a servlet, both here and at springsource.org, and I still can't get it working.

All I want to do is have the datasource automatically set in my servlets.  I understand that the container creates the servlet and not Spring.

Here is code from my test servlet:

```
package mypackage.servlets;

imports go here...

@Service
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet
{
  private JdbcTemplate _jt;

  @Autowired
  public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
  {
    _jt = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }

  etc etc
```

In my applicationContext.xml I have:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="mypackage.servlets />
<import resource="datasource.xml" />
```

and in my datasource.xml:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/db" />
```

If I can't get this working I'll just use WebApplicationContextUtils in the servlet's init method but I'd really like to make this work after all the reading I've been doing.

I'm using Spring 3, Java 1.6.

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: It would be helpful to explain more as to how it's not working, what you've tried, what kind of errors you're having, etc. Just saying it's not working doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: Why not use a Spring MVC Controller? Autowiring will only work if Spring creates the beans. And even though you annotate the servlet with @Service your container is going to create a Servlet instance when it gets a request.

Comment: AHungerArtist - I should have made it clear that I was expecting setDataSource to be called and it wasn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wanted to do was get a DataSource reference in my Servlet for free, i.e. not calling a static getDatasource method on some class.

Here's what I learned and how I got it working:

Servlets cannot be configured or autowired by Spring.  Servlets are created before Spring's app context is loaded.  See issue SPR-7801: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7801

What I did was create a DataSource in my applicationContext.xml and export that as a property:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/db" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAttributeExporter">
  <property name="attributes">
    <map>
      <entry key="myDatasource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
      </entry>
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

In my servlet's init method I read the property:

```
public void init(ServletConfig config)
{
  Object obj = config.getServletContext().getAttribute("myDatasource");
  setDataSource((DataSource)obj);
}

public void setDataSource(DataSource datasource)
{
  // do something here with datasource, like 
  // store it or make a JdbcTemplate out of it
}
```

If I'd been using DAOs instead of hitting the database from the servlets it would have been easy to wire them up for @Autowired by marking them @Configurable, and also be able to use @Transactional and other Spring goodies.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace your Servlets by Spring MVC contollers. Because Spring will not inject anything the classes (servlets) created by someone else then Spring itselfe (except @Configurable).

(To get an very simple example, take a look at the STS Spring Template Project: MVC).

Comment: I suppose I'm trying to have my cake and eat it too.  We've got all this existing code - I'm trying to upgrade our JDBC calls by using Spring JDBC, without rewriting the whole web app.